# AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'split'. What is wrong?

Tags: python

```py
class SquareMatrix:

    def __init__(self, order):
        self.order = order
        self.rows = [
            [0 for j in range(order)]
            for i in range(order)]

    def __str__(self):
        x = ''
        for row in self.rows:
            x = x + ' '.join(map(str, row))+'\n'
        return x

    def set_value(self, i, j, value):
        self.rows[i][j] = value

    def get_value(self, i, j):
        self.rows[i][j]

    def max(self):
        tomliste = []
        for i in self.rows:
            for num in i:
                tomliste.append(num)
        tomliste.sort()
        return tomliste[-1]

    def min(self):
        tomliste = []
        for i in self.rows:
            for num in i:
                tomliste.append(num)
        tomliste.sort()        
        return tomliste[0]

    def trace(self):
        counter = 0
        for i in range(self.order):
            counter = counter + int(self.rows[i][i])
        return counter

    def summary(self):
        lib = {(f'order : {self.order}, max : {self.max()}, min : {self.min()}, trace : {self.trace()}')}
        return lib

    def save(self, filename):
        f = open(filename, "w")
        f.write(str(self))
        f.close()


    @classmethod
    def parse(cls, text):
        liste = []
        for line in text.split('\n'):
            liste.append(line.split())

        matrix = SquareMatrix(len(liste[1]))

        for i, line in enumerate(liste):
            matrix.rows[i] = line
        return matrix

    
    @classmethod
    def load(cls, filename):
        y = open(filename, 'r')
        y = y.read
        y = SquareMatrix.parse(y)
        return y


m1 = SquareMatrix(3)
m1.set_value(1,1,7)
m1.get_value(2, 1)
print("--m1--")
print(m1)
print(m1.summary())


m2_text = """\
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9"""
print("--m2--")
m2 = SquareMatrix.parse(m2_text)
print(m2)
print(m2.summary())
m2.save("m3.txt")


print("--m3--")
m3 = SquareMatrix.load('m1.txt')
print(m3)
print(m3.summary())
```

Im quite new to programing and can't figure out what has to be done. when finished it should look like this:

```py
--m1--
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1
{'order': 3, 'max': 1, 'min': 0, 'trace': 3}
--m2--
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
{'order': 3, 'max': 9, 'min': 1, 'trace': 15}
--m3--
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
{'order': 3, 'max': 9, 'min': 1, 'trace': 15}
```

error:
File "c:\Users\marle\Documents\INFO132\maped6868_hoved2.py", line 96, in 
m3 = SquareMatrix.load('m1.txt')
File "c:\Users\marle\Documents\INFO132\maped6868_hoved2.py", line 72, in load
y = SquareMatrix.parse(y)
File "c:\Users\marle\Documents\INFO132\maped6868_hoved2.py", line 58, in parse
for line in text.split('\n'):
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please update the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: You didn't call `read`. You need to write `.read()` not `.read`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is in your `load` method:

```py
 @classmethod
    def load(cls, filename):
        y = open(filename, 'r')
        y = y.read
        y = SquareMatrix.parse(y)
        return y
```

The line `y = y.read` is not calling the read function, it's just a reference to the function, so `SquareMatrix.parse(y)` is doing `SquareMatrix.parse(y.read)` which is a function and not a string.

`y = y.read()` will fix the current error you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your `load` classmethod to return a single string, then you need to call the "read" function. You're returning a function instance in your case. This should fix it:

```py
    # ...

    @classmethod
    def load(cls, filename):
        with open(filename, 'r') as file:
            # file.read is a function, so you call it with (). This returns a string.
            y = file.read() 
        return SquareMatrix.parse(y)
```

I also added a small best-practice detail. When opening files you always want to do it by using a `with open() as file:` context manager. This prevents memory leaks if an error occurs.